# Difference between `if` statements

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, logical-operators

Am newbie in programming, just curious, what is the difference between

```
if(a == 1)
{
    //condition
}
if(b == 1)
{
    //condition
}
```

and

```
if(a == 1 || b == 2)
{
    //condition
}
```

I don't have any questions regarding this, all I want is clarification. Don't over think guys, I know you're all pro's. Take note on the "just curious", cause am noob.

Comment: that's what tutorials are used for, not SO. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: In first case you can execute two different codes depending if a = 1 or b = 1, in second case you will execute the same code if a = 1 or if b = 1

Comment: this is the wrong place for that kind of questoins. Those are logical operators. Search on G.

Comment: @bub yeah, so you people aren't doin/workin with which it here

Comment: for one, only in the control expression of the second code snippet mentions the literal `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement compares the variable 'a' to '1', and if the variable 'a' is equal to '1', then you will execute the block of code enclosed in brackets. Likewise, the first statement also compares the variable 'b' to '1' and if equal will execute a block of code.

The second expression evaluates two conditions, 'a' being equal to 1, and 'b' being equal to '2'. If either expression is true, then the block of code enclosed in brackets will execute. The double pipe symbol '||' is synonymous with 'or'.